# How to get a specific action for every InlineKeyboardButton in Telegram bot using Python?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

so I am really new with programming and learning something everyday.

I have found an InlineKeyboard code here somewhere and changed it so it will work properly on telegram(using python-telegram-bot).

Now I'm trying to understand how to make a specific action, for example when user press on 'Submenu 1-1' button it should reply with a text message or command, and different action for 'Submenu 1-2'.

I have tried to define 'm1_1' callback_data with CallbackQueryHandler but still no success.

Please see the code below:

```
import logging

from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def start(update, context):
  update.message.reply_text(main_menu_message(),
                            reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard())

def main_menu(update, context):
  query = update.callback_query
  context.bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=query.message.message_id,
                        text=main_menu_message(),
                        reply_markup=main_menu_keyboard())

def first_menu(update, context):
  query = update.callback_query
  context.bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=query.message.message_id,
                        text=first_menu_message(),
                        reply_markup=first_menu_keyboard())

def second_menu(update, context):
  query = update.callback_query
  context.bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=query.message.message_id,
                        text=second_menu_message(),
                        reply_markup=second_menu_keyboard())

def third_menu(update, context):
  query = update.callback_query
  context.bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                        message_id=query.message.message_id,
                        text=third_menu_message(),
                        reply_markup=third_menu_keyboard())

def first_submenu(update, context):
  pass
def second_submenu(update, context):
  pass
def third_submenu(update, context):
  pass

def main_menu_keyboard():
  keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Option 1', callback_data='m1')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Option 2', callback_data='m2')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Option 3', callback_data='m3')]]
  return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

def first_menu_keyboard():
  keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Submenu 1-1', callback_data='m1_1')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Submenu 1-2', callback_data='m1_2')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Main menu', callback_data='main')]]
  return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

def second_menu_keyboard():
  keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Submenu 2-1', callback_data='m2_1')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Submenu 2-2', callback_data='m2_2')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Main menu', callback_data='main')]]
  return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

def third_menu_keyboard():
  keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Submenu 3-1', callback_data='m3_1')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Submenu 3-2', callback_data='m3_2')],
              [InlineKeyboardButton('Main menu', callback_data='main')]]
  return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

def main_menu_message():
  return 'Choose the option in main menu:'

def first_menu_message():
  return 'Choose the submenu in first menu:'

def second_menu_message():
  return 'Choose the submenu in second menu:'

def third_menu_message():
  return 'Choose the submenu in third menu:'


def main():
  updater = Updater('TOKEN', use_context=True)

  ud = updater.dispatcher


  ud.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
  ud.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(main_menu, pattern='main'))
  ud.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(first_menu, pattern='m1'))
  ud.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(second_menu, pattern='m2'))
  ud.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(third_menu, pattern='m3'))
  ud.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(first_submenu,
                                                    pattern='m1_1'))
  ud.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(second_submenu,
                                                    pattern='m2_1'))
  ud.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(third_submenu,
                                                    pattern='m3_1'))




  updater.start_polling()

  updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

peace&love :]
Solved**
It looks like the program was recognizing 'm1' and 'm1_1' as the same callback data, I guess it's to similar , when I changed 'm1_1' to 'p3' it worked

Comment: in first_submenu function, you should use the code to reply to the user. `update.message.reply_text("you clicked on m1_1")`. Have you tried it?

Comment: @AliPadida Yes, I have tried, and it says to me "message is not modified: specified new message content and reply markup are exatly the same as a current content and reply markup of the message"

Comment: It would only say that if you try to edit the message. You should reply to message, and if you want to edit the message, you should make some changes, like different text or different keyboard.

Comment: @AliPadida I understand what you say, but still, I edited first_submenu def to update. Message.reply_text('hi) and added commend handler for' m1_1' and still the 'Submenu 1-1' button recognize the same callback, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AliPadida thank you for answering :) can't believe I spent two days trying to solve that haha